# How to set dynamic minorTickInterval according to the datarange in Highstock?

Tags: highcharts

I used configured Highstock's "tickPositioner" to set ticks dynamically for different ranges of data. For example, if the range is 1 hour max => 1 tick every 10 minutes. Here is some code of the function I put in tickPositioner (which is in xAxis config):

```
if (xDataRange <= oneHour) {
     // If range is 1 hour max => 1 tick every 10 minutes
      increment = oneMinute*10;
      positions.info.unitName = "minute";              
    } else if (xDataRange > oneHour && xDataRange <= oneDay) {
     // If range is between 1 hour and 1 day => 1 tick every hour
      increment = oneHour;
      positions.info.unitName = "hour";
    } else { ... }
```

Here is an illustrating fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/E6GHC/124/
(I know that the range choices are not the best here.)

The QUESTION:  I would like to do the same with the minorTicks.
As you can see in the Fiddle, when you click on the month button the ticks are positionned each week and minorTicks are each day. But this is static configuration (`minorTickInterval: oneDay`).

I have some ideas and I have tried them and nothing seems to work out.. 
So if someone have any suggestion ? I would be veryyy thankful.
The perfect thing would have been to be have to set/update the minorTickInterval in tickPositioner function.

Comment: You can update axis via axis.update({minorTickInterval: /* Number */}) http://jsfiddle.net/vkbf54rg/

Comment: Thank you @morganfree , I am aware of that but I was looking for a way to change this interval according to the period of display. For example between one hour and one day, in addition of the major ticks placed every hour, I would like to have minor ticks placed every 30mn. And for a period between one day and one week (where major ticks are placed every day, for example) to place minor ticks every 12 hours, and so on.. I tried something with an update at each click on the selector button but if we use the navigator there isn't any adaptation as you can see (http://jsfiddle.net/E6GHC/125/)...